# How to do a colour box around text

Tags: color, box

I need make a colour box for put in my command from cmd but i don't know how to do it.

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks and rewards.

Comment: Maybe the examples under documentation of `\DeclareTotalTCBox` are helpful, see [documentation of `tcolorbox` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), section 23.3.

Comment: For simple coloured boxesn you can use `\colorbox{background colour}{contents}` or `\fcolorbox{framecolour}{background colour}{contents}`. See in `xcolor` documentation: §2.6.2 Colored boxes, pp.22-23